# Expectation of Euclidean Norm and Quadratic Forms

Tags: multivariate-analysis, quadratic-form, expected-value

If $\boldsymbol{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}_p(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$, can someone please help me understand why $\mathbb{E}[||\boldsymbol{\beta}||_2^2] = ||\boldsymbol{\mu}||_2^2 + \text{trace}(\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$

Further, how does this expectation change if we instead consider  $\boldsymbol{\beta}^T\textbf{W}\boldsymbol{\beta}$, where $\textbf{W}$ is a diagonal matrix?

Thank you!

Comment: This post  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables/442916#442916    answers you last implied question.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48066/119261

Answer (score 1):

$E[\beta]$ quantifies the expected squared Euclidean distance of a vector from the origin. 
The relation you stated holds for any random vector with finite second moment. 
It implies that the expected distance depends on the distance from the mean ($\mu$) to the origin, and the expected variability around this mean ($Trace(\Sigma)$).

$\beta W \beta$ is the Euclidean norm iff $W$ is the identify matrix. 
For general properties of moments of random quadratic forms, you can consult Section 6.2.2 in the [Matrix CookBook] (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), and references therein.

Answer (score 1):

The proof for the first question requires only some simple properties of the trace operator, the expected value, and the definition of the covariance matrix (see [here](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Est849-1/lectures/Ch02.pdf)). First, as mentioned in the title, $||\mathbb{\beta}||^2$ is a quadratic form, given by $||\mathbb{\beta}||^2 = \beta^T \beta$. Then we have:

$$ \mathbb{E}\left( \beta^T \beta \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( tr(\beta^T \beta) \right) \\ = \mathbb{E} \left( tr(\beta \beta^T) \right) \\
= tr \left(\mathbb{E} \left( \beta \beta^T \right) \right) \\
= tr \left(\Sigma + \mu \mu^T\right) \\
= tr \left(\Sigma \right) + tr \left(\mu \mu^T\right) \\
= tr \left(\Sigma \right) + tr \left(\mu^T \mu \right) \\
= tr \left(\Sigma \right) + \mu \mu^T = tr \left(\Sigma \right) + ||\mu||^2
$$

Here we just used a couple of basic probability and linear algebra properties:

1. In line 1, because $\beta^T \beta$ is a scalar, $\beta^T \beta = tr(\beta^T \beta)$
2. In line 2, we use the equality for the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) of a product that says $tr(A^TB) = tr(AB^T)$
3. Because the trace is linear, we can [move the expected value operator inside the trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3004034/948036)
4. From the definition of the [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix), it can be shown that $\mathbb{E} \left( \beta \beta^T \right) = \mathbb{E}((\beta-\mu)(\beta-\mu)^T) + \mu\mu^T = \Sigma +  \mu\mu^T$
5. We use that the trace is linear, i.e. $tr(A+B) = tr(A) + tr(B)$.
6. We again use the fact that $tr(A^TB) = tr(AB^T)$
7. Because $\mu^T \mu$ is a scalar, we remove the trace operator (same as step 1), and $\mu^T \mu = ||\mu||^2$