# Proof $E[Z'TZ]^2=\operatorname{tr}^2(T)+\operatorname{tr}(T^2)$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, matrix, linear-algebra

How to prove second moment of a quadratic form where $Z$ has normal distribution with mean zero and covariance matrix identical?

Comment: Also, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/expected-value-of-quadratic-form

Comment: In the one-variable case with $T=(t_{11}),$ you are asking us to show $$t_{11}=  t_{11}E[Z^2] =E[t_{11}Z^2]  = E[Z^\prime T Z] =\operatorname{tr}^2(T) + \operatorname{tr}(T)^2 = t_{11}^2+t_{11}^2 = 2t_{11}^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}.$ Then $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA).$ The proof of that is routine.

So we have $Z\sim N_n(0, I_n)$ and $T\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}.$ Then
\begin{align}
& \operatorname E(Z'TZ) = \operatorname E(\operatorname{tr}(Z'TZ)) = \operatorname E(\operatorname{tr}(TZZ')) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname{tr}(\operatorname E(TZZ')) \quad \text{since tr is linear} \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname{tr}(T\operatorname E(ZZ')) \quad \text{since $T$ is constant} \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname{tr}(T I_n) = \operatorname{tr}(T).
\end{align}
So it appears that your proposed identity is mistaken